# What is the best way to recover cron job

Tags: unix, aix

I entered crontab -r instead of crontab -e and all my cron jobs have been removed.

What is the best way  to recover those jobs?

It is a AIX server.

Comment: In case I have not taken a backup then what should be my approach.kindly help.

Comment: The file is *gone*. Barring a backup, good memory, or a chance of an old copy somewhere, you have a manual reconstruction job on your hands.

Comment: I have got a suggestion that after deleting the jobs are stored in /var/spool/cron/crontabs directory.But since i don't have root permission I am not able to open that folder.    Will it be a helpful approach and should I ask the client for root permission .

Comment: The directory `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` is where the crontab resides until you remove it with `-r`. There are no backups in there. If you got a copy of all the unused blocks on the partition and tried to find things that looked like crontabs you might be able to find it (or pay for a recovery tool). However after even 30 minutes a partition like `/var` will have been written to extensively so the content is most likely gone. You're in [exactly this situation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136350/recover-cron-jobs-accidently-removed-with-crontab-r).